# What would be the best way to evaulate the database management systems?

Tags: sql-injection, databases, audit, account-security

I am an Information security analyst, looking for creative, non traditional, and unapproved ways to query/evaluate DBMS applications that includes SQL Server and PostgreSQL. Goal here is to protect the organization that I work for from nefarious SQL injections or data leakage. I would appreciate if anybody can provide links to the documents/books/queries/tools that are applicable in current environment.

Comment: DBMS's are not to blame for SQL Injections nor data leakage. Web apps, faulty authentication and/or bad passwords are. VTC'd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand your requirements, so I will assume you want to prevent offering vulnerabilities to nefarious actors, rather than pen-testing until doomsday.
Further assumptions:
- You are connected enough with your organization to review source code with the developers.

I would start with the OWASP recommendations.
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Much of this will rely upon scanning the source code rather than rigging up a framework to feed your databases sketchy queries.  Please let me know in comments if this is NOT what you mean, or if your INFOSEC group is not tied in with the developers.